# using Android Universal Image Loader in acivity inside library project

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

i have problem on calling activity inside library

i use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

inside activity in library project. i setup it inside application class in main project that use library

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-
Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/UILApplication.java

but when i want use it in acitivity that are inside library return this error
"ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using is the error from Illegal State Exception
how can i solve it

Comment: i think you can use Picasso-2.3.1.jar to solve problem

Answer (score 1):

For your solution you need to use this

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imgLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(YourActivityName.this));
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error).considerExifParams(true)
            .build();
```

Comment: where should i use it?, should use this code for each activity oncreate method

Comment: Yes you have to use it onCreate() method. And want to access imgLoader  variable anywhere in that class then make variable global.

Comment: ok,so i can't access variable inside appmain(that extends application) in activities inside library? what should i do for thats?

Comment: Yes you can also use in that but after using it you have init it this way. And if you want to use that you can find it on google